# Why is this variable not updated during the loop?

Tags: pic, pwm, pulldown, code

I`m trying to obtain a PWM signal from RA4 a PWM signal when a button is pressed (button connected to RA2) using a PIC12F1572. I'm in trouble with code because run as follow:

1. Start simulation via Proteus -> 0 PWM (good, because button is released).
2. Push button (let current flow) -> RA2 (name semnalizare in code) = 1 -> I get corect PWM value.
3. Release button -> PWM still here even if RA2 (semnalizare =0).
   What happened here? As I know, when check statement (in this case if (semnalizare == 1)) is placed in while (1) must be checked every time continously. Why is it not "updated" with 0 value after the button is released?

Code and test circuit below.

I use this to learn how PIC works and like a hobby.

[image: Circuit for testing]

A strange thing happened running: thr voltage goes down.
I missed someting strange: during testing output voltages goes down.

[image]

```c
/*
 * PIC12F1572 PWM example.
 *
 * Pins:
 *                     +----+
 *                Vdd -|1  8|- Vss
 *           PWM1 RA5 -|2  7|- RA0/ICSPDAT
 *           PWM2 RA4 -|3  6|- RA1/ICSPLCK
 *           RA3/MCLR -|4  5|- RA2 PWM3
 *                     +----+
 */

#include <xc.h>

#define _XTAL_FREQ 16000000   // Oscillator frequency.

#pragma config FOSC = INTOSC  // INTOSC oscillator: I/O function on CLKIN pin.
#pragma config WDTE = OFF     // Watchdog Timer disable.
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF    // Power-up Timer enbable.
#pragma config MCLRE = ON     // MCLR/VPP pin function is MCLR.
#pragma config CP = OFF       // Program memory code protection disabled.
#pragma config BOREN = ON     // Brown-out Reset enabled.
#pragma config CLKOUTEN = OFF // CLKOUT function is disabled; I/O or oscillator function on the CLKOUT pin.
#pragma config WRT = OFF      // Flash Memory Write protection off.
#pragma config STVREN = ON    // Stack Overflow or Underflow will cause a Reset.
#pragma config BORV = LO      // Brown-out Reset Voltage (Vbor), low trip point selected.
#pragma config LVP = OFF      // High-voltage on MCLR/VPP must be used for programming.

#define pwm_1  PORTAbits.RA5
#define pwm_2  PORTAbits.RA4
#define frana  PORTAbits.RA3
#define semnalizare PORTAbits.RA2
#define pozitie PORTAbits.RA1


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void init_pic() {
    OSCCON = 0b01111010; // 16 Mhz oscillator.
    ANSELA = 0b00000000;// 0b-prefix pentru binar bit:0b76543210
    //bit7=RA5(0 digital input, 1= analog input) PWM_1
    //bit6=RA4(0 digital input, 1= analog input) PWM_2
    //bit5=RA3(0 digital input, 1= analog input) Frana
    //bit4=RA2(0 digital input, 1= analog input) Semnalizare
    //bit3=RA1(0 digital input, 1= analog input) Pozitie
    //bit2=RA0(0 digital input, 1= analog input)
    //bit1- nefolosit (set to 0)
    //bit0- nefolosit (set to 0)
    LATA = 0;            // Zero all port bits.
}

void init_pwm() {
    // Pin selection.
    APFCONbits.P1SEL = 1; // PWM1 on RA5.
    APFCONbits.P2SEL = 1; // PWM2 on RA4.

    // Set PWM pins to be outputs.
    TRISAbits.TRISA5 = 0;  //RA5 = PWM_1 = OUTPUT
    TRISAbits.TRISA4 = 0;  //RA4 = PWM_1 = OUTPUT
    // Set input pins.
    TRISAbits.TRISA3 = 1;  //RA3 = frana = INPUT
    TRISAbits.TRISA2 = 1;  //RA2 = semnalizare = INPUT
    TRISAbits.TRISA1 = 1;  //RA1 = pozitie = INPUT
    // Set HFINTOSC clock, no prescaler.
    PWM1CLKCON = 0b00000001;
    PWM2CLKCON = 0b00000001;

    // PWM control (standard mode).
    PWM1CON = 0b11000000;
    PWM2CON = 0b11000000;

    // Phase.
    PWM1PH = 0;
    PWM2PH = 0;

    // Duty cycle.
    //PWM1 =RA5  PWM2=RA4 PWM3=RA2
    PWM1DC = 13333; //= duty_cycle * (PERIOD/100);  //RA5
    PWM2DC = 24000; //RA4

    // Period.
    PWM1PR = 26667; //PERIOD
    PWM2PR = 26667;

    //On
    PWM1LD = 0;
    PWM2LD = 0;
}

//RA5= frana cerc mic (PWM1)
//RA4= semnalizare cerc mic (PWM2)
int main() {
    init_pic();
    init_pwm();
    PWM1LD = 0;
    PWM2LD = 0;

    while (1)  
    {
        if (semnalizare == 1)
        {
            PWM2LD = 1;        
            PWM2DC = 20000;// PWM=50%
            __delay_ms(10);
        }
        else 
        {
            PWM2LD = 0;
            PWM2DC = 0;
            __delay_ms(10);
        }

        if (semnalizare == 0)
        {
            PWM2LD = 0;
            PWM2DC = 0;
            __delay_ms(10);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem may be that you cannot change PWM characteristics once it has already started. When you do your else loop (btw your else loop and your if semnalizare == 0 loops are redundant), try disabling PWM, then changing those values, then reenabling PWM. Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39194940/dspic33-updating-pwm-duty-and-frequency

Comment: Well, it's not a variable. It's a macro definition which ends up as code which reads input status. And maybe the code does do different things based on buttom being pressed or not, so it might just be that the button reading works fine, the PWM control not, so you are looking for solving the wrong problem. Always debug first, maybe turn a LED on or off based on buttom first, then when you know it works, try doing more complex stuff.

Comment: It is usually better to use a pull-up with switch to GND, and 100k is too weak. 4.7k or 10k would be more reliable. As @G36 said, to use a pull-down, the weak internal pull-up should be disabled. The weak pull-up is about 50k, so it will cause the input to be in an intermediate (undefined) logic state.

Answer (score 2):

The main function should look like this:

```c
  
 int main() {
      
    init_pic();
    init_pwm();
  
   while (1)  
  {
    
     if (semnalizare == 1)
     {
       PWM2LD = 1;        
       PWM2DC = 13334;// PWM=50% for PWMPH = 0 Duty = PWMDC/(PWMPR + 1)
       __delay_ms(10);
     } 
     else 
     {
      PWM2LD = 1;
      PWM2DC = 0;
      __delay_ms(10);
     }
  }
}
```

And you should probably also disable the pull-up resistor for the PA2 pin in init_pic() function.

```
WPUAbits.WPUA2 = 0; // PULL-UP disable
```

And in Proteus try to change oscilloscope channel A from AC coupling to the DC coupling.

Answer (score 2):

You have your fake oscilloscope set to AC coupling so it will settle out with 0V average.

Set it to DC to see the actual values.